# Jsp Flow For search and update Form

Tags: javascript, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I have 3 jsp . Lets call them search.jsp,showResult.jsp,updateResult.jsp.
In search.jsp i have 8 fields according to which i have to search the results from database. So when i submit the search.jsp ,it call showResult.jsp , in which i am getting all these fields using request.getParameter.
After that i show all the results in showResult.jsp. All the result rows have Details button in the last, and when i click it , i opened a popup which has all the details and i can update it. The popup also have some files input type to upload images.

So my problem is , when i click the update button i call the updateResult.jsp and after updating the values , how can i go again to showResult.jsp with the same search results.

I dont want to use URL rewriting as it make the URL long and show all the values in url.
I cannot use AJAX to update becoz how can i get the path of a file in j.s methos.

Please help  me.
vikas

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the popup from the original window: one way is to use Ajax and replace the content of the popup with the HTML results of the new search results. IMO I wouldn't use a popup, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment dave but this popup i used is not a new window . It is just displaying a div and hiding the background(All Results). It is a jquery popup.

Comment: How it is easier . How can i pass the value from update form to show result form without url rewriting. And i can use request.setAttribute but i have to create many checks on showResult form. Is there any other idea .As i mentioned I cannot use AJAX becoz in update i can upload images and for ajax i have to call a javascript function and in that function i can not get the whole path of uploaded file, and i want the whole path.

Comment: I don't really know what you're saying.

Comment: I have one form in which i enter different search criteria. And another form in which i show results according to search criteria. In this show result form i have one button in the end of each row which shows all the details of that result. When we click on this button i opened a jquery popup. And in this popup i can  upload photos and update other entries. So when i click on update button i call the updateResult.jsp. After updation how can i go back to showResult.jsp witout URL rewriting.

Comment: What URL would you rewrite? Are you saying that you want to re-run the search after you update the individual record?